# runit startup script without pause

Tags: runit

I am using a runit based linux distro (artix) and I would like to run a script **once** at startup with the root user. To achieve this I usually create a service with this kind of *run* script:

```
#!/bin/bash
<my command here> & pause
```

This allow the command to run once when the service is started, but this keep a useless process alive. Is there a cleaner way to tell runit that a service script should be run **once** ?